# How do I include gl-matrix?

Tags: javascript, math, webgl

What I did:

Downloaded master branch from here: https://github.com/toji/gl-matrix
Put src folder into my project's folder.
Included gl-matrix-manifest.js from there.
Tried this:

```
var mvMatrix = mat4.create();
```

Result:

```
var mvMatrix = mat4.create();
ReferenceError: mat4 is not defined
```

Okay, let's indlude mat4 directly. Included. Result:

```
var out = new GLMAT_ARRAY_TYPE(16);
ReferenceError: GLMAT_ARRAY_TYPE is not defined
```

Okay, maybe it needs common.js:

```
var x = axis[0], y = axis[1], z = axis[2],
TypeError: axis is undefined
```

WTF, included all other files from src folder (common, vectors,matrices,quat):

```
var x = axis[0], y = axis[1], z = axis[2],
TypeError: axis is undefined
```

(same)

How do I include propertly? In particular I need mat4 and vec4.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just include /dist/gl-matrix-min.js or /dist/gl-matrix.js  :)

Answer (score 20):

Once the source is specified correctly, I still couldn't directly call mat4.

I had to type "glMatrix.mat4" instead.

Comment: Seems to be a "feature" of 3.0 version. Version 2.4 (linked in Mozilla WebGL tutorial) works with `mat4` just fine, version 3.0 (taken from `glmatrix.net`) doesn't. Writing `var mat4 = glMatrix.mat4;` simplifies things a bit.

Comment: Alternatively, with ES6, you can use object destructuring to just write something like `const { mat4, mat3, vec3 } = glMatrix;`

Comment: `window['mat4'] = glMatrix.mat4; console.log(mat4);` But ES6 option is better.

Answer (score 4):

Add this cdn link in head

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gl-matrix/2.8.1/gl-matrix-min.js"
        integrity="sha512-zhHQR0/H5SEBL3Wn6yYSaTTZej12z0hVZKOv3TwCUXT1z5qeqGcXJLLrbERYRScEDDpYIJhPC1fk31gqR783iQ=="
        crossorigin="anonymous" defer>
</script>
```

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

1. Download from [here](https://github.com/toji/gl-matrix/zipball/master)
2. Extract and take gl-matrix-min.js
3. In your index.html file `<script src="gl-matrix-min.js"></script>`
4. Now try `var mvMatrix = glMatrix.mat4.create();`

Comment: Step 3 gives me the error `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: Is there another solution that doesn't require downloading an unknown zip file?

Comment: Yes, You can add cdn `<script src"https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gl-matrix/3.4.2/gl-matrix-min.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Another source of cdn `<script src="https://unpkg.com/gl-matrix@3.4.3/cjs/index.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

The next two examples shows a modern way how to include glMatrix and Box2D-WASM as ES6 modules using import maps.

Playground that shows how to initialize Box2D-WASM to create and print a Box2D vector: https://plnkr.co/edit/BGNYcIJRiJXpd9N4?preview

The next playground shows how to use glMatrix only:

```html
    <!-- Since import maps are not yet supported by all browsers, its is
        necessary to add the polyfill es-module-shims.js -->
    <script async src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/es-module-shims@1.8.3/dist/es-module-shims.min.js"></script>

    <script type="importmap">
        {
            "imports": {
                "box2d-wasm": "https://unpkg.com/box2d-wasm@7.0.0/dist/es/Box2D.js",
                "gl-matrix": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gl-matrix@3.4.3/+esm"
            }
        }
    </script>

    <script type="module">
        import { glMatrix, mat4, vec3 } from "gl-matrix";

        console.log(glMatrix.toRadian(45));

        const v = vec3.fromValues(1, 2, 3);
        console.log(v);

        const m = mat4.create();
        console.log(m);
    </script>
```